# Border.IsMouseOver in RichTextBox ( InlineUIContainer in RichTextBox does not respond to event/trigger )

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, richtextbox

Say I have the following:

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="7,2,10,2" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="RoyalBlue" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="7,2,10,2" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>

        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="7,0,7,1" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Run}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
        </Style>

    </Grid.Resources>

        <FlowDocument >

            <Paragraph>

                <Span>

                    <Border>

                        <TextBlock>Test</TextBlock>

                    </Border>

                </Span>

            </Paragraph>

        </FlowDocument>

    </RichTextBox>

</Grid>
```

The style triggers work beautifully when the Border is outside of the RichTextBox, but not when they are inside an InlineUIContainer in a RichTextBox.

I am able to get the desired behavior by setting the properties in the code behind by use of the MouseOver event and by using the VisualTreeHelper.HitTest() method, but I'm pretty sure this is terribly inefficient and can't help but think there is a much better way to approach this?

If anyone could offer some guidance here, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to search the deepest and darkest corners of the internet to find this one, but it looks like there is a hack to enable events for InlineUIElements within a FlowDocument:

```
public class EventEnabledFlowDocument : FlowDocument
{
    protected override bool IsEnabledCore
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that there are likely some nasty side effects from doing this, but it seems to work for my purposes. One side effect I am aware of - event handlers will not be saved if you delete an InlineUIElement and then undo that deletion.

Comment: Another side effect is if you save/load the document as a xaml string that property doesn't do the trick! Any idea how to work around that?